# Thymeleaf and AngularJS2

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, thymeleaf

I created a sample app using latest Angular2 as my client-side MVC framework and Thymeleaf for the server-side templating engine. I used Eclipse IDE to build dynamic WebApp with Spring and Thymeleaf. I built an Angular project separately using Angular CLI tool and generated deployment Javascript files which were added to the eclipse project under js folder as shown here,

[image]

But this is not the way to go with a real complex project as we need simultaneous development of Angular2 and Spring/Thymeleaf and cannot really on deployment Javascript files.

What is the ideal way to develop Spring/thymeleaf and Angular2 project in Eclipse IDE? What are the tools available ? Has anyone encountered this sort of problem ?

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343157/can-i-use-angular2-and-thymeleaf-together

Comment: Thanks @Yasin directing to that question, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. There are many applications developed using Thymeleaf and Angular1. But this is not straightforward with angular2.